# Python multiprocessing fails to terminate on KeyboardInterrupt, freezing Windows

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I have a simple function, getHashes(), that calculates a checksum when supplied with a list/dict of data. I am using multiprocessing to calculate these hashes in parallel, using multiple cores. However, if I CTRL + C to end the process, my entire machine locks up. I am using Python 3.6 on Windows 10. Here is the 
function for reference:

```
def syncHashes():
    """ 
    main function
    """
    #Initialize
    print("Starting the scanner in root " + rootDir)

    #Start the multiprocessing pool
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=10)

    for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
        # Convert filenames to full paths...
        full_path_fnames = map(lambda fn: os.path.join(dirName, fn), 
                           fileList)

        #Only add valid files
        full_path_fnames = filter(is_valid_file, full_path_fnames)

        try:
            #Send all files in the directory to the getHashes function
            results = pool.map(getHashes, full_path_fnames)
            pool.close()

            #Necessary to allow CTRL+C interruptions
            for item in results:
                item.wait(timeout=9999999)

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pool.terminate()
        finally:
            pool.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    syncHashes()
```

I tried adding a wait to allow the worker threads to finish, but this is still unsuccessful. Any help would be greatly appreciated.